# GeoServer how to permit to user to see only the his data

Tags: geoserver, user-interface

I am beginner in GeoServer use.
I want to create different users in my server, however I don't know how to allow to each user the access for his data only, and how can he grant access to other specific users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to look into Layer security access documentation, which is based on roles and access rules.

In you case you could assign a specific role to a user and give access to selected layers to this role using rules.

Take a look into:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html